# Email address via google places API

Tags: email, google-maps, google-places-api

At the moment it is only possible to display company address and phone number through google places. Is there anyway the company Email address can be obtained even if its not displayed through the google places api or any other google api.

If not do you think this is on the roadmap for google places API

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned on the [Google Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4148), this is not possible and their are no plans to offer email address through the Places API because it would make it too easy to scrape email addresses for the purposes of spamming companies concerned.

Comment: so then how are things like the G-Business Extractor (chrome extension) getting emails?